# Expect raised error at compile time with ChefSpec

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

My Chef cookbook is raising a compile time error which I want to expect in a ChefSpec test.

Cookbook Snippet

```
if !windows_version.windows_server_2012_r2? 
    error = "Not supported on this version of Windows"
    raise error
end
windows_package 'Server2012 Only Package' do
    action :install
end
```

Unit Test Snippet

```
it 'Throws error' do
    expect(chef_run).to raise_error
end
```

But this does not catch the error and pass the test.  I receive the compile time error instead and the test fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use curly brackets [when testing exception with RSpec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher):

```ruby
it 'Throws error' do
    expect { chef_run }.to raise_error
end
```